# Predicting dates of future product purchase based on past purchase patterns

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I figure there must be some way to do this with all of Google's Cloud AI tools, but I don't know where to start.

I have a dataset with:

- User ID
- Product ID
- Purchase Date

I want to analyze the data to determine for each user, if there is a pattern of regular purchases of a product over time.  For example, Customer X buys Product Y every 4 days.  Or, projections of the dates Customer X will buy Product Y again.

How would I go about that with Google's AI tools?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-keras

Comment: Thanks - that looks super-complex to me, and requiring Python experience.  Is there an easier path for my use case?

Comment: I’ll tell you that AI is more closer to statistics and data analysis than programming. You’ll need to shift your approach to it.